# Convert Config text file into XML

Tags: xml, text, txt2tags

I copied config in txt file, and I'm having a hard time to convert it into xml format.
I have this kind of file that is .txt file.

```
unknown-applications 
      unknown-tcp 
        destinations-per-hour 10
        sessions-per-hour 10
        session-length 
          maximum-bytes 100
          minimum-bytes 50


      unknown-udp 
        destinations-per-hour 10
        sessions-per-hour 10
        session-length 
          maximum-bytes 100
          minimum-bytes 50




  report 
    topn 500
    scheduled yes
```

and it should be converted to something like this in a XML file.

```
<unknown-applications>
      <unknown-tcp>
        <destinations-per-hour>10</destinations-per-hour>
        <sessions-per-hour>10</sessions-per-hour>
        <session-length>
          <maximum-bytes>100</maximum-bytes>
          <minimum-bytes>50</minimum-bytes>
        </session-length>
      </unknown-tcp>
      <unknown-udp>
        <destinations-per-hour>10</destinations-per-hour>
        <sessions-per-hour>10</sessions-per-hour>
        <session-length>
          <maximum-bytes>100</maximum-bytes>
          <minimum-bytes>50</minimum-bytes>
        </session-length>
      </unknown-udp>
    </unknown-applications>
  </configuration>
  <report>
    <topn>500</topn>
    <scheduled>yes</scheduled>
  </report>
```

Is it possible to automate this process?

The text config file is about 9000 lines.

I would greatly appreciated by any help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could read your file line by line, add each line to a stack.
when you see a new line, you add an opening tag to your file, when you find a space, you add the value then the clofing tag. when you find a blank line, you unstack to add the closing tags to your file.